# Word for a someone who likes food or likes to eat.

Tags: food

Not necessarily greedy but someone who can't say no to food or easily attracted to food. Not to excess, not selfish either. In someway like a curious child who keeps eyeing your food or a child who would snatch food like it is his/her own.

Answer (score 4):

A *foodie* is someone with an interest in food, usually one who makes a 
hobby out of it—trying new restaurants, cooking, and so on. I think that’s the best fit.

Near-synonyms don’t seem to fit the bill. A *gourmand* is someone who enjoys eating, but this often implies that they eat too much. An *epicure*, *gourmet*, or *gastronome* is someone more specifically interested in *fine* food.

Comment: Foodie is it. :) Maybe the OP was looking for a stricter, less recent term. (Dreading the find in some book from the 18th century that happens to mention it.)

Comment: I forward _gastronome_ as a less recent synonym foodie. The same type of people would go to markets, perform experiments in the kitchen, etc. A foodie perhaps to a lesser extent, but I think a lot of foodies would be gastronomes, because they are often food nerds.